# A sum of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions

> How would you prove that $$\sum_{n \ \text{odd}} \text{sgn}(a + nb ) e^{- | a + n b |} = - \frac{\sinh(a)}{\sinh(b)}$$

where $|a| <  b$ and the sum runs over all odd integers between $-\infty$ and $+ \infty$?

Comment: We can write:

$$\sum_{\text{n}\space\text{odd}}\frac{\text{sgn}\left(\text{a}+\text{n}\text{b}\right)}{\exp\left(\left|\text{a}+\text{n}\text{b}\right|\right)}=$$
$$\sum_{\text{n}=-\infty}^0\frac{\text{sgn}\left(\text{a}+\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\text{b}\right)}{\exp\left(\left|\text{a}+\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\text{b}\right|\right)}+\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{\text{sgn}\left(\text{a}+\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\text{b}\right)}{\exp\left(\left|\text{a}+\left(2\text{n}+1\right)\text{b}\right|\right)}$$

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: For the right sum (that starts at $\text{n}=1$ and go to $\infty$), you can say (using the ratio test): $$\exp\left[-2\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{b}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{b}\right)}\right]<1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we may write the series as $$S\left(a,b\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\textrm{sgn}\left(a+\left(2n+1\right)b\right)e^{-\left|a+\left(2n+1\right)b\right|}
 $$ now note that $$a+\left(2n+1\right)b>0\Leftrightarrow n>-\frac{a+b}{2b}.
 $$ Since $\left|a\right|<b
 $ we get $$-b<a<b
 $$ hence $$-1<-\frac{a+b}{2b}<0
 $$ so we have $$S\left(a,b\right)=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\left\lfloor -\frac{a+b}{2b}\right\rfloor }e^{a+b+2nb}+\sum_{n=\left\lfloor -\frac{a+b}{2b}\right\rfloor +1}^{\infty}e^{-a-b-2nb}
 $$ $$=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}e^{a+b+2nb}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-a-b-2nb}
 $$ now from the well knonw identity $$\sum_{k=m}^{n}x^{k}=\frac{x^{n+1}-x^{m}}{x-1}
 $$ we get $$S\left(a,b\right)=-\frac{e^{a+b}}{e^{2b}-1}+\frac{e^{b-a}}{e^{2b}-1}=\color{red}{-\frac{\sinh\left(a\right)}{\sinh\left(b\right)}}$$ as wanted.